# MonoMac - AVAudioPlayer crash

Tags: c#, .net, avaudioplayer, monomac

We are having an issue using `AVAudioPlayer` on MonoMac.

We get this warning on the console:

```
Class AVAudioPlayer is implemented in both ?? and /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Which is followed by `Segmentation fault: 11` and an immediate crash.

I'm assuming my MonoMac app is somehow loading the iOS libraries for `AVAudioPlayer`. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, I built MonoMac from source and referenced my new MonoMac.dll directly and it fixed it. Any Xamarin guys think this is just a problem with the version of MonoMac bundled with MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin just released Xamarin.Mac, which fixes this issue.